# Auto increment in db2

Tags: sql, db2

i have created a table which auto increments the id values starting with 100 with an increment of 100, but after 1000 and the next data is inserted it jumps to 2000, where it should be 1100.

this is the syntax:

```
create table student(  
id int not null generated always as identity(start with 100, increment by 100),  
name varchar(30),  
primary key(id)  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the database was re-activated before you saw the ID value of 2000. Values for identity columns and for sequences are cached for performance reasons. The default for identity columns is ["cache 20"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html?lang=en).

When the cache is filled with a chunk of new values, the next base line is persisted in the DB2 catalog. When a database is de-activated (shut down, last connection closed), all caches are destroyed, too. After reconnecting to a database when the next ID value is needed, DB2 first looks for an existing cache, then retrieves the last base line from the catalog. In your case that would be 2000 (20*100).

Comment: what syntax should i add which will run as i want? 1000->1100 but not 2000. cache(10)?

Comment: That would be `no cache`. See the linked document above for the syntax options. The number after cache determines how many values are cached and you don't want any gaps. It may have performance impact though.